# Without using trace, how to tell if flash application is in a container?

Tags: flash, trace, externalinterface

I'm trying to determine if my flash content is inside a container. I have no idea what this means, but apparently it's bad for making ExternalInterface.calls. I'm developing the site on a linux machine I'm running the server on and I'm working with the flash on a windows machine. I've tried many options for using trace, none of them have worked. Is there any way to see if ExternalInterface is available w/o using trace? Current code is here: http://pastebin.com/f5fe9a985 Another post I've made on the subject is here:  [Flash trace output in firefox, linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825316/flash-trace-output-in-firefox-linux)

Thanks,
Dan

also, the actionscript is 2.0, if that helps...

Answer (score 0):

You should really spend an afternoon with the docs for flash player's security and javascript stuff. I think it would really help you in understanding how this all works.

Some clarification is needed for your q:

You say you are running a server on your linux box, but your swf is on a windows machine? Can you explain that setup? (it shouldn't matter that they are linux vs. windows, only what domain they are served from (or local machine name).

If your local machine is http://localhost

and your windows machine is http:// mywindowsbox/

then you'll need to allow access to the html page that the swf is embedded on, by adding allowscriptaccess=always in your embed code.