# Run Jquery function on actionscript 2.0

Tags: jquery, actionscript-2

I have a function in jquery I would like run in flash using action script 2.0

The Jquery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){  
$("a").click(function(event){
            $("div#Header").height(97)
             .css({cursor:"auto", backgroundColor:"#FCC"});
 });
});
</script>
```

The Html

```
<a href="#">Run</a>
```

How I do this in actionscript 2.0?

Answer (score 2):

[ExternalInterface](http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/638/1/Basics-of-using-the-ExternalInterface/Page1.html) lets you call Javascript functions from Flash.  The simplest thing to do would be to place your code inside a Javascript function defined in the HEAD of the page (or otherwise above where the SWF is embedded), then call:

```
ExternalInterface.call("yourFunctionName");
```

More on ExternalInterface in [this old SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818089/using-externalinterface-in-flashp).

Comment: Thanks Ben, but my problem is not to run javascript so I do this "getURL("javascript:popupMessage()");" works well, but a jquery I am having trouble.