# actionscript 3 command to use in a button to save a signature without options

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

There is a div in my project, and this project is on-line. Inside this div there is a space that is made in flash (actionscript 3), inside this space we have to sign a contract with the mouse. How can I save this signature without an options window to choose where I want to save this signature?

(The button to save the signature is made in flash too).

Comment: You can send the image data to a server no problem. For security reasons, in the browser you cannot save a file locally without the user seeing a dialog box. To save a file locally you need AIR or another swf wrapper to gain file writing access without a "save" dialog box.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds fun :)  Flash can [rasterize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rasterisation) any DisplayObject (including the entire Stage) [as a Bitmap](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?266493-Extract-Bitmap-or-BitmapData-from-MovieClip).  You can then [encode this Bitmap into a compressed image format, such as a JPEG](http://designreviver.com/tutorials/actionscript-3-jpeg-encoder-revealed-saving-images-from-flash/).  From there you could either send this JPEG directly to a remote server, or, use [ExternalInterface to send it a JavaScript method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818089/using-externalinterface-in-flash) in the same HTML Page!

Good luck!